# use custom URL for azure vm ssh

Tags: ip, azure, forwarding, subdomain

So I would like to use a custom url subdomain to ssh (using SSH-2 / RSA) into an azure vm. It has a static public IP and I have created a subdomain forwarding to the public ip.

Currently I ping the subdomain and get a ip that is not the forwarded IP

www and @ both head to a website.

Is it reasonable to expect this to work or is there a cname and alias combination I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

for an azure vm with a public ip only a cname for a given subnet on the DNS managing software is necessary.

In my case I was hung up because the VM firewall needed the same rules the azure NSG used.

The upshot is that simply making a cname rule of host 'sample' with value/target of the servers public ip 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' was sufficient even having checked the ports were listening I still needed to open the firewall.

dumb mistake but there it is.